# Julia: All possible sums of `n` entries of a Vector with unique integers, (with repetition)

Tags: julia, combinatorics

Let's say I have a vector of unique integers, for example `[1, 2, 6, 4]` (sorting doesn't really matter).

Given some `n`, I want to get all possible values of summing `n` elements of the set, including summing an element with itself. It is important that the list I get is *exhaustive*.

For example, for `n = 1` I get the original set.
For `n = 2` I should get all values of summing 1 with all other elements, 2 with all others etc. Some kind of memory is also required, in the sense that I have to know from which entries of the original set did the sum I am facing come from.

For a given, specific `n`, I know how to solve the problem. I want a concise way of being able to solve it for any `n`.

EDIT: This question is for Julia 0.7 and above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Julia 0.6**

This is really just to get a free critique from the experts as to why my method is inferior to theirs!

```
using Combinatorics, BenchmarkTools

function nsum(a::Vector{Int}, n::Int)::Vector{Tuple{Int, Vector{Int}}}
    r = Vector{Tuple{Int, Vector{Int}}}()
    s = with_replacement_combinations(a, n)
    for i in s
        push!(r, (sum(i), i))
    end
    return sort!(r, by = x -> x[1])
end

@btime nsum([1, 2, 6, 4], 3)
```

It runs in circa 4.154 μs on my 1.8 GHz processor for `n = 3`. It produces a sorted array showing the sum (which may appear more than once) and how it is made up (which is unique to each instance of the sum).

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark. Your answer is not only much, much easier to understand, but it is also **20 times faster** that the answer of Robert, at least on Julia 0.7. I am wondering, why does `s` return vectors instead of tuples? Well, anyway, even though it creates vectors it is still much faster!

Comment: Ops, I was too quick to judge. Your answer is actually incorrect. It *does not* give all possible combinations... If you run your example you will see that the entry `[4, 4, 6]` does not exist. In general the returned vector should have `length(a)^n` entries, but in the current example it has 20 instead of 64.

Comment: But on the other hand, maybe I can still use it: to my understanding your answer gives the combinations that have *unique* entries. So, since I care about their sums, I can take the entries that I care, and them to use them I have to call an arbitrary `shuffle` on them, to get a random order out of all possible ones.

Comment: Yeap, this approach is by far the fastest. By the way, you can make your function much faster by first not sorting (at least in my OP I did not care about this) and by doing `r = Vector{Tuple{T, Vector{Int}}}(undef, binomial(m + n - 1, n))` where `m = length(a)`. The length of returned vector is known analytically.

Comment: I thought you meant combinations rather than permutations, and my solution produces [6, 4, 4] which in combination terms is the same as [4, 4, 6]. In fact my method produces exactly the same combinations as Bogumil's dictionary-based solution below (which is something I checked before I posted my answer). Apologies if I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical task where you can use a dictionary in a recursive function (I am annotating types for clarity):

```
function nsum!(x::Vector{Int}, n::Int, d=Dict{Int,Set{Vector{Int}}},
               prefix::Vector{Int}=Int[])
    if n == 1
        for v in x
            seq = [prefix; v]
            s = sum(seq)
            if haskey(d, s)
                push!(d[s], sort!(seq))
            else
                d[s] = Set([sort!(seq)])
            end
        end
    else
        for v in x
            nsum!(x, n-1, d, [prefix; v])
        end
    end
end

function genres(x::Vector{Int}, n::Int)
    n < 1 && error("n must be positive")
    d = Dict{Int, Set{Vector{Int}}}()
    nsum!(x, n, d)
    d
end
```

Now you can use it e.g.

```
julia> genres([1, 2, 4, 6], 3)
Dict{Int64,Set{Array{Int64,1}}} with 14 entries:
  16 => Set(Array{Int64,1}[[4, 6, 6]])
  11 => Set(Array{Int64,1}[[1, 4, 6]])
  7  => Set(Array{Int64,1}[[1, 2, 4]])
  9  => Set(Array{Int64,1}[[1, 4, 4], [1, 2, 6]])
  10 => Set(Array{Int64,1}[[2, 4, 4], [2, 2, 6]])
  8  => Set(Array{Int64,1}[[2, 2, 4], [1, 1, 6]])
  6  => Set(Array{Int64,1}[[2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 4]])
  4  => Set(Array{Int64,1}[[1, 1, 2]])
  3  => Set(Array{Int64,1}[[1, 1, 1]])
  5  => Set(Array{Int64,1}[[1, 2, 2]])
  13 => Set(Array{Int64,1}[[1, 6, 6]])
  14 => Set(Array{Int64,1}[[4, 4, 6], [2, 6, 6]])
  12 => Set(Array{Int64,1}[[4, 4, 4], [2, 4, 6]])
  18 => Set(Array{Int64,1}[[6, 6, 6]])
```

EDIT: In the code I use `sort!` and `Set` to avoid duplicate entries (remove them if you want duplicates). Also you could keep track how far in the index on vector `x` in the loop you reached in outer recursive calls to avoid generating duplicates at all, which would speed up the procedure.

Answer (score 2):

> I want a concise way of being able to solve it for any n.

Here is a **concise** solution using [IterTools.jl](https://juliacollections.github.io/IterTools.jl/stable/):

#### Julia 0.6

```julia
using IterTools
n = 3
summands = [1, 2, 6, 4]
myresult = map(x -> (sum(x), x), reduce((x1, x2) -> vcat(x1, collect(product(fill(summands, x2)...))), [], 1:n))
```

(*IterTools.jl is required for `product()`*)

#### Julia 0.7

```julia
using Iterators
n = 3
summands = [1, 2, 6, 4]
map(x -> (sum(x), x), reduce((x1, x2) -> vcat(x1, vec(collect(product(fill(summands, x2)...)))), 1:n; init = Vector{Tuple{Int, NTuple{n, Int}}}[]))
```

(*In Julia 0.7, the parameter position of the neutral element changed from 2nd to 3rd argument*.)

#### How does this work?

Let's indent the one-liner (using the Julia 0.6 version, the idea is the same for the Julia 0.7 version):

```julia
map(
  # Map the possible combinations of `1:n` entries of `summands` to a tuple containing their sum and the summands used.
  x -> (sum(x), x),
  # Generate all possible combinations of `1:n`summands of `summands`.
  reduce(
                # Concatenate previously generated combinations with the new ones
    (x1, x2) -> vcat(
                    x1,
                    vec(
                        collect(
                            # Cartesian product of all arguments.
                            product(
                                # Use `summands` for `x2` arguments. 
                                fill(
                                    summands,
                                    x2)...)))),
  # Specify for what lengths we want to generate combinations.
  1:n;
  # Neutral element (empty array).
  init = Vector{Tuple{Int, NTuple{n, Int}}}[]))
```

Comment: Very nice! Probably you want to also do `filter(x->length(x[2])==n, myresult)` to get only sums of `n` elements. Also note that this version keeps duplicate entries.

Comment: Thanks! this looks very concise indeed! Unfortunately I can't understand it, it is probably "too" concise for someone that doesn't know the answer.(I can clearly see that it does what I want, but some explanation would make the answer more appealing).

Edit: this code also doesn't run on Julia 0.7, I updated my OP to say that I am working with Julia 0.7

Comment: Sorry: the answer you provided does work with Julia 0.7, one has to replace `using IterTools` with `using Iterators`. That was a confusion from my part!

Comment: Hm, I don't understand why your answer works for `n = 2` at Julia 0.6 but fails for `n = 2` at Julia 0.7 with error `ERROR: ArgumentError: number of columns of each array must match (got (1, 4))`

Comment: Yet another comment: The correct way to make it work on Julia 0.7 is to do: 
`map(x -> (sum(x), x),
        reduce((x1, x2) -> vcat(x1, vec(collect(product(fill(summands, x2)...)))), [n];
        init = Vector{Tuple{Int, NTuple{n, Int}}}[]))`

Comment: @GeorgeDatseris Re: Iterators.jl vs IterTools.jl

Hmm, afaik Iterators.jl is deprecated in favor of IterTools.jl? For me, IterTools.jl works with Julia 0.7.

Comment: Re: The correct way to...  Huh, yeah, looks like the parameter position of the neutral element changed with Julia 0.7 (that should explain the error, as you probably already found out).

Comment: Updated the answer to contain your requested amendments.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations Robert, I appreciate it a lot. In 0.7 there is an `Iterators` module in Base. So you do `using Base.Iterators` instead of `using IterTools`. The *GitHub* repository of Iterators.jl is indeed deprecated.